# Mac: Execute program when joining a specific wireless network

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, wireless-networking

My question is essentially the same as [this](https://superuser.com/questions/92414/how-to-run-a-program-when-connecting-to-a-specific-network-in-windows-7) one, but for OS X 10.6 instead of Windows 7.

I would like to run a program whenever I connect to my home wireless network (not the one at work or university).  I'm sure there's a program that does this, but unfortunately my google-fu isn't strong today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**MarcoPolo**](http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/) is what you're after, it can run scripts via [**Platypus**](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus) upon changing a network so you can make a shell script to launch your program.

Comment: @John: looks like it will do the trick nicely, thank you sir!  (and how cool is it that my 1st SU question is answered by the Jon Skeet of SU?!)