# How to define when machine was connected to WiFi in Windows logs?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, troubleshooting, logging

I'm looking for a ways to define time when WiFi connection was established/enabled/disabled on Windows 7 machine through logs.

The reason I'm looking for it is that I have laptops in LAN which connected through the wired network but also have a WiFi enabled. Spontaneous switching to WiFi or just connecting to WiFi and wired network simultaneously at times lead to quirk issues in some applications and I need to check whether at a time or before error in my application WiFi connection was established or disabled to define whether it is a cause of an issue.

Answer (score 2):

I found answer to my question here:
[How to run a program when connecting to a specific network in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/92414/how-to-run-a-program-when-connecting-to-a-specific-network-in-windows-7)

Event ID 8001 for successful WiFi connection and 8003 for disconnect are being recorded in Applications and Services > Microsoft > Windows > WLAN-AutoConfig > Operational. For wired connection there are events 10000 (connected) & 10001 (disconnect) in Applications and Services > Microsoft > Windows > Network Profile Operational.

Through creating custom view in event viewer it can be combined with application error in on view to analyze if there is any connection between these events.