# Home NAS backup system

Tags: backup, ftp, automation, nas

my question is about automatiom and backups.

So I go to work and generate about 1GB of files a day, i want to have a NAS at home that when i come home with my laptop and connect to the network it uploads all my outstanding files to the server then removes them from my laptop automatically. What software would I go about using for this? I'll be getting a Synology NAS.

I also need access to these files off the NAS at home and work but I already understand the FTP setup for that. I'm a Windows user, but I'm linux literate for any server side config.

I've looked at a bunch of softwares so far, but nothing has been clear that it could support this. Only timed or manual back ups really. Happy to hear about non-free software too.  thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you looked at the Synology applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found for automatically moving files its best to stay as simple as possible and the simplest way is always command line. So I would first map the NAS on the laptop, then create a batch file that moves the files and then using Task Scheduler, create a task that runs when it connects to your home network.

[task scheduler option 1](https://superuser.com/questions/262799/how-to-launch-a-command-on-network-connection-disconnection)

[task scheduler option 2](https://superuser.com/questions/92414/how-to-run-a-program-when-connecting-to-a-specific-network-in-windows-7)